# How create stored procedure in specific database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want create stored procedure when i create my database with variable name.

For create my database, at the top of the script I write `USE [master] GO`.

After I want to create my stored procedure in my new database but I can't specify the database in my query like this:

```
DECLARE @DB_NAME sysname
select @DB_NAME = valeur from #vars WHERE nom = 'DB_NAME'   /*Nom de la base de données*/

SET @SqlCommand = 'CREATE PROCEDURE '+ @DB_NAME +'.[dbo].[sp_DEFRAG_Index]

@Pourcent int  = 30.0

AS BEGIN
```

Error :

> Msg 166, Level 15, Status 1, Line 317
>
> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL for this? It would be easier to switch to the database you want and execute a proper `CREATE PROCEDURE`.  Instead of `USE [master]` use the database you really want

Comment: Just in case you're trying to reinvent the wheel, [this might be relevant](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

Comment: Please post errors as text not images and ensure you translate them.

Comment: The [syntax does not support that](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql#syntax). You can only create procedures in the currently active database. Use `USE` to switch. Also, don't use the `sp_` prefix for your own sprocs, as this is reserved for system sprocs. Especially something with a generic name like `sp_defrag_index` has a bad potential to clash.

Comment: I want create database, table and stored procedure in same script and when I write
`SET @SqlCommand = 'USE EXELIS_TS_ALARM2'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlCommand
GO`
It doesn't work.
My stored procedure is created in master db.

Comment: For the "sp_" prefix I saw that in the documentation but I haven't taken the time to change that yet.

Comment: And Stu for the link I will look in more detail but it seems complicated for a novice like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `sp_executesql` dynamically, that is: you can create a value containing `'DB_NAME.sys.sp_executesql` then call `EXEC @name @params`

```sql
DECLARE @DB_NAME sysname;
select @DB_NAME = valeur
from #vars
WHERE nom = 'DB_NAME';   /*Nom de la base de données*/

DECLARE @SqlCommand nvarchar(max) = '
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DEFRAG_Index]

@Pourcent int  = 30.0

AS
';

DECLARE @spexecute nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@DB_NAME) + '.sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC @spexecute @SqlCommand;
```